# Insert between each occurrence of two characters

Tags: sed

If I can have somewhere in my input a series of two or more characters (in my case, `>`), how can I insert something between **each** occurrence of `>`?

For example: `>>` to `>foo>`, but also:
`>>>` to `>foo>foo>` and:
`>>>>` to `>foo>foo>foo>`.

Using `'s/>>/>foo>/g'` gives me of course `>foo>>foo>`, which is not what I need.

In other words, how can I push a character back to the pattern space, or match a character without consuming it (does that make any sense?)

Comment: Do you have super-sed `ssed`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Perl, you can do it iteratively

```
$ echo '>>>>' | perl -pe 's/>>/>foo>/ while />>/'
>foo>foo>foo>
```

or use a look-ahead assertion, which does not consume the 2nd `>`

```
$ echo '>>>>' | perl -pe 's/>(?=>)/>foo/g'
>foo>foo>foo>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should also work

```
sed ':b; s/>>/>foo>/; tb'
```